Tomcat return 404 when calling api
Im start to make a test api springboot and when im deploy it on tomcat http://localhost:8080/demoApp/api/v1/person it is return 404.
Here is my controller file:
@RequestMapping("api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {
private final PersonService personService;

@Autowired
public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
    this.personService = personService;
}

@PostMapping
public void addPerson(@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody person person) {
    personService.addPerson(person);
}

@GetMapping(path = "{id}")
public person getPersonById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id) {
    return personService.getPersonById(id)
            .orElse(null);
}

@GetMapping
public List<person> getAllPeople() {
    return personService.getAllPeople();
}



@DeleteMapping(path = "{id}")
public void deletePersonById(@PathVariable("id") UUID id) {
    personService.deletePerson(id);
}

@PutMapping(path = "{id}")
public void updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") UUID id,@Valid @NonNull @RequestBody person person) {
    personService.updatePerson(id, person);
}

}`
im just test api so that im not making any html file and when im calling http://localhost:8080/demoApp/api/v1/person it is return 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
But when i add helloworld.html at http://localhost:8080/demoApp/ it still working

Did you try http://localhost:8080/demoApp/api/v1/person/3756bea2-9c90-40d8-926e-34cf631c75e9 (change 3756bea2-9c90-40d8-926e-34cf631c75e9 to the UUID of a person in your database, i.e. a value personService.getPersonById will accept)?

Read up on Spring Boot URL routing.  That is likely the issue.

i tried the http://localhost:8080/demoApp/ without helloworld.html then it return 404 while in other video it return whitelabel, is that any problem in there

Which of your methods are you trying to access by URL (e.g. getPersonById, getAllPeople, etc.)?

Try http://localhost:8080/api/v1/person
demoApp is your app name and not related to the request path. With @RequestMapping("api/v1/person") and the empty @GetMapping, your request url should be http://localhost:8080+/api/v1/person.
